# Remove youtube vide title on android webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I'm writing an application that plays video from youtube using WebView. There is no problem with playing but video has it's own header, that is not so useful for me. How can remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a javascript file which would accomplish this action, 
and later inject it using loadUrl method on onPageFinished [reference](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/)

Answer (score 0):

i have full solution for customized iframe of youtube video

```
WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView back_btn;

    String video_url = "KK9bwTlAvgo", html = "";

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.full_screen_youtube_video_screen);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        back_btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_videoview_btn);
            back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    webView.loadData("", "text/html", "UTF-8");
                    finish();
                }
            });

            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
               progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            if (video_url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                finish();
                return;
            }

            WebSettings ws = webView.getSettings();
            ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
            ws.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.reload();

            if (networkUtil.isConnectingToInternet(Act_VideoPlayer.this)) {
                html = getHTML(video_url);
            } else {
                html = "" + getResources().getString(R.string.The_internet_connection_appears_to_be_offline);
                CustomToast.animRedTextMethod(Act_VideoPlayer.this, getResources().getString(R.string.The_internet_connection_appears_to_be_offline));
            }

            webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");

            WebClientClass webViewClient = new WebClientClass(progressBar);
            webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
            WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient();
            webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    }




    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            webView.loadData("", "text/html", "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        try {
            webView.loadData("", "text/html", "UTF-8");
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public class WebClientClass extends WebViewClient {
        ProgressBar ProgressBar = null;

        WebClientClass(ProgressBar progressBar) {
            ProgressBar = progressBar;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            LogShowHide.LogShowHideMethod("webview-click :", "" + url.toString());
            view.loadUrl(getHTML(video_url));
            return true;
        }
    }

    public String getHTML(String videoId) {
        String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" " + "style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 96%;"
                + "padding:0px; margin:0px\" " + "id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" "
                + "src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoId
                + "?&theme=dark&autohide=2&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1\fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\" "
                + "allowfullscreen autobuffer " + "controls onclick=\"this.play()\">\n" + "</iframe>\n";
        LogShowHide.LogShowHideMethod("video-id from html url= ", "" + html);
        return html;
    }
```